# Create DOM elements and set a click event in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, click, bind

how can I create in an *AngularJS* directive some DOM elements and set on them a **click event**? In my directive I create my elements in this way:

```
var list = document.createElement("div");
list.classList.add('myList');
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var item = document.createElement("div");
        item.classList.add('myItem');
        list.appendChild(item);
}
```

so I have an external div container that contains some *div elements*.
This is my generated HTML:

```
<div class="myList">
    <div class="myItem">
    <div class="myItem"></div>
    <div class="myItem"></div>
    <div class="myItem">
</div>
```

In the same directive I have to set a *click event* on those elements, in *jQuery* I can do:

```
$(".myItem" ).on( "click", function() {
    // Do something
});
```

I try to that in *Angular* in many ways but I have problems to set the on click event:

```
var list = document.querySelector('.myList');
_.forEach(list.children, function(value, index){
        var item = document.querySelector(value);
        item.bind("click",function(){
        // Do something
    });
});
```

I get an error:

```
Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object HTMLDivElement]' is not a valid selector.
```

Also, if I want get all myItem directly (without *list.children*) I write use:

```
var item = document.querySelector('.myItem');
```

I get:

```
item.bind is not a function (caused by "undefined")
```

I can set an ng-click in the directive... how?

```
item.on( "click", function() {
     // Do something
});
```

If I use .on() method it's undefined like .bind().

Anyone can help me? Thanks in advice :)

Comment: You need to add ng-click to your HTML.

Comment: Hi, thanks but how can I create an ng-click in the directive? If I use .on('click', function(){...}); I have problem with .on() method that it's undefined like .bind()

Comment: ng-click is a built-in directive.  Post your HTML.  It's hard to help you without seeing all of your code.

Comment: I updated my question, I generate HTML in the directive and them I want to put a click event on those elements. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is

```
<div class="myList">
<div class="myItem" ng-click="yourClickFn()">
<div class="myItem" ng-click="yourClickFn()"></div>
<div class="myItem" ng-click="yourClickFn()"></div>
<div class="myItem" ng-click="yourClickFn()">
```

Then in your Angular controller:

```
$scope.yourClickFn = function(){

  //the code you want to execute here

}
```

Comment: My HTML is generate in the directive with document.createElement() so I can't put ng-click in this way,  I have to put a click dinamically but the problem is that I'm unable to get the rigth reference with query selector and apply .on() or .bind()

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a real reason to create your elements this way? It's really not the angular-way of doing things. You should use an ng-repeat on to create your html.

Also if you have a chance to update to anguar 1.5+ you could use components instead of directives, this would make your life easier.

**Update**

Alternatively you could do it with jQuery after the elements are created actually. I think it's easier to read than the plain js version.

Put a class on them and do something like:

```
$('.myClass').on('click', function() {
       //your code
       if (!$scope.$$phase) { // this checks whether you are already in a digest cycle or not - you probably won't be at this phase.
          $scope.$apply(); // this will update the html if you did something to the model above this if
        }
   });
```

If you have a directive put this code to the link function, if you have a component then put it into the $postLink lifecycle hook (works after 1.5.3 I think) as these functions are called after your html has been already generated.
Usually these are the places for "messy" or "non-angular" code ^_^

Comment: HTML is already created in this way, my job is create a click event so it's better if I don't change previous code... I can't updated my angular version :(.. so is there no way out? It's so easy with jquery...

Comment: Updated my answer with a jQuery + angular version